# Get controller instance in IOperationBehavior attribute

Tags: c#, wcf

I develop an attribute that implements `IOperationBehavior`, it will be used to control access to actions of my WCF controller. I need to call instance method of  controller to retrieve some information that I need to make decision about to allow or deny access.

Is there any way to get an instannce when framework calls `ApplyDispatchBehavior(OperationDescription description, DispatchOperation dispatch)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An invoker, that I have to pass to `DispatchOperation` instance's `Invoker` field, has access to an instance, so I can apply final verification steps there.